# How to import object from typescript file in javascript file?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, import, fs

I have `constants.ts` file:

```
    export const docs = {
      "0x1": {id: "1"},
      "0x2": {id: "2"}
    }
```

And i need to import in my `.js` script file `script.js` import from `contsants.ts` somehow:

```
console.log(import from contants.ts)

    {
      "0x1": {id: "1"},
      "0x2": {id: "2"}
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended-up doing this:

```
// script.js

const filecontent = fs.readFileSync(PATH_TO_TS_FILE, {encoding: 'utf-8'})
const contracts = JSON.parse(filecontent.replace('export const docs = ', '').replace(/id:/g, '"id":'))

for(key in contracts) {
   console.log(contracts[key])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> And i need to import in my .js script file script.js import from contsants.ts somehow:

Target: You want to log out docs from constants.

Steps to get there:

- Compile your `.ts` to `.js` using TypeScript `tsc`.
- Now use the compiled `.js` file from your js file

Example:

```
const constants = require('./constants'); 
console.log(constants.docs); // Prints as required.
```

Comment: Is any way to import without creating outside `.js` file compiled files ?. Basically i want to run `node scripts.js`. No pre compilation.

Comment: export const docs = {
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 0